# JS library path not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

When running the bellow code locally (WAMP), it works fine. When I upload it to the server, it won't include jQuery unless I add it to the folder "js". What am I missing when including libraries from other folders? I checked a million times, that the path is correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/com.js"></script>
```

**(Edit)** The files in are arranged as follows 
**root**

```
lib    //(folder)
js     //(folder)
index.html
```

**-js**

```
com.js
zepto.js
```

**-lib**

```
jquery
```

**--jquery**

```
jquery.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js
```

Comment: With the way your src attributes are constucted, I would assume you have a lib folder in your main_html where you are keeping those js files?

Comment: js and lib are on same brach ?

Comment: where is your js and lib folder?